# How to pass variables from one View Controller to another in WatchOS 2 & Swift

Tags: variables, swift2, viewcontroller, watchos-2, watchapp

I am having a lot of problems trying to get a couple of variables from one View Controller to the next. How can I do it properly?
Here's my code below. This is the view controller where I want to be able to send the variables `RedScoreW` and `BlueScoreW` to the next window. I am asking on HOW TO DO THIS using SWIFT language and specially for WATCHOS apps.

```
class InterfaceController2: WKInterfaceController {

    var RedScoreW = 0
    var BlueScoreW = 0


    @IBOutlet var WatchRedScoreLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet var WatchBlueScoreLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

    @IBAction func RedScorePlus() {
        if RedScoreW == 999 {
            RedScoreW = 0
            WatchRedScoreLabel.setText("0")
        }else {
            RedScoreW += 1
            WatchRedScoreLabel.setText(String(RedScoreW))
        }
    }
    @IBAction func RedScoreMinus() {
        if RedScoreW == 0 {
            RedScoreW = 999
            WatchRedScoreLabel.setText("999")
        }
        else {
        RedScoreW -= 1
        WatchRedScoreLabel.setText(String(RedScoreW))
        }
    }

    @IBAction func BlueScorePlus() {
        if BlueScoreW == 999 {
            BlueScoreW = 0
            WatchBlueScoreLabel.setText("0")
        } else{
        BlueScoreW += 1
        WatchBlueScoreLabel.setText(String(BlueScoreW))
        }
    }

    @IBAction func BlueScoreMinus() {
        if BlueScoreW == 0 {
            BlueScoreW = 999
            WatchBlueScoreLabel.setText("999")
        }
        else {
            BlueScoreW -= 1
            WatchBlueScoreLabel.setText(String(BlueScoreW))
        }
    }

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        WatchRedScoreLabel.setText(String(RedScoreW))
        WatchBlueScoreLabel.setText(String(BlueScoreW))


        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }


}
```

And this is the Destination View Controller where I want to be able to use RedScoreW and BlueScoreW variables.

```
class InterfaceController3: WKInterfaceController {


    @IBOutlet var finalRedScoreLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

    @IBOutlet var finalBlueScoreLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

    @IBAction func DoneAndResetButton() {
        self.popToRootController()
    }

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)


        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()
    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

}
```

*** EDIT ***

I am trying to do it this way, this is the code where I send it, check:

```
  @IBAction func FinishButtonPushVariables() {

        arrayofScores[0] = RedScoreW
        arrayofScores[1] = BlueScoreW

        pushControllerWithName("LastScreen", context: arrayofScores)

    }
```

And this is where I receive it... and it doesn't work. LOL

```
  @IBOutlet var finalRedScoreLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

    @IBOutlet var finalBlueScoreLabel: WKInterfaceLabel!

    @IBAction func DoneAndResetButton() {
        self.popToRootController()
    }


    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        let finalarrayofScores = context as? InterfaceController2

        finalBlueScoreLabel.setText(String(finalarrayofScores!.arrayofScores[1]))
        finalRedScoreLabel.setText(String(finalarrayofScores!.arrayofScores[0]))



        // Configure interface objects here.
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing Data between View Controllers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Comment: Not at all. The link you provide is for Objective C, and iOS, I am asking about WatchOS and Swift 2. Thanks!

Comment: Is there much of a difference?

Comment: Yeah :-/ I am learning swift, and Objective C it's seems to me to be very complicated for me :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In iOS apps, we use `prepareForSegue` to do this. On watchOS apps, we use `contextForSegueWithIdentifier` to pass a context from one interfaceController to another.

Here is a link to the [class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceController/contextForSegueWithIdentifier:) that will detail more about this. But here are the basics:

There are two different methods that can be used. One is for going from one interface controller to another:

`func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(_ segueIdentifier: String) -> AnyObject?`

The other is for going from a one interface controller to another **when a row in a table is tapped**:

`func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(_ segueIdentifier: String, inTable table: WKInterfaceTable, rowIndex rowIndex: Int) -> AnyObject?`

So one of these two methods will go in the interfaceController that is sending the context, and you will receive that context in the `awakeWithContext` method of the receiving interfaceController.

Here is a [link](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/52810/how-do-i-pass-data-between-screens-in-my-apple-watch-apps/) to a tutorial that will show an application of this process.

**EDIT**

Here is a specific solution to your problem.

In the interface controller where you send it, put this code:

```
override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String) -> AnyObject? {
    arrayofScores[0] = RedScoreW
    arrayofScores[1] = BlueScoreW
    return arrayOfScores
}
```

Then in your destination interface controller, put this code:

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
    super.awakeWithContext(context)
    let finalArrayOfScores = context as? [Int]

    if let f = finalArrayOfScores {
        finalBlueScoreLabel.setText(String(f[1]))
        finalRedScoreLabel.setText(String(f[0]))
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! This really solved my problem. And you have helped me learn to use the contextForSegue function. Thank you one more time.

Comment: No problem, I am glad that it helped!

Comment: Wow contextForSegue is beautiful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up variables to hold your variable first.

```
class YourSecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var yourVariable:Double?
}
```

Then have your button trigger your custom segue. Use your variable as the argument for sender.

```
class YourFirstViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: yourVariable)
    }
}
```

Then pass the sender data by overriding the prepareForSegue method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier = "segue") {
        let secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController as YourSecondViewController
        let yourVariable = sender as Double
        secondViewController.duration = yourVariable
    }
}
```

Comment: But does this work on WatchKit? because I write "prepareforsegue" and it does not auto-complete :(

Answer (score 1):

I guess your problem is that you are passing an array to the context and you cast it as WKIntefaceController.
Try replacing this line

```
 let finalarrayofScores = context as? InterfaceController2
```

by

```
let finalarrayofScores = context as? [Int]
```